# Why SIM900 with ATMEGA328PU give different Result when given inputs from different PC's Arduino Serial Monitor?

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, atmega, arduino-ide, sim900

I have Connected SIMCOM900 with ATMEGA328PU on a breadboard. It is giving correct outputs when inputs are given by one PC's Arduino Serial Monitor but with another PC's Arduino serial monitor's input (with the same circuit )it is not even responding. What is the reason behind? (Outputs are attached)

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//SIM800 TX is connected to Arduino D8
#define SIM800_TX_PIN 10

//SIM800 RX is connected to Arduino D7
#define SIM800_RX_PIN 11

//Create software serial object to communicate with SIM800
SoftwareSerial serialSIM800(SIM800_TX_PIN,SIM800_RX_PIN);


void setup() 
{
  //Begin serial comunication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);
  //Being serial communication witj Arduino and SIM800
  serialSIM800.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("Setup Complete!");
}

void loop()
{
  //Read SIM800 output (if available) and print it in Arduino IDE Serial Monitor
  if(serialSIM800.available()){
    Serial.write(serialSIM800.read());
  }
  //Read Arduino IDE Serial Monitor inputs (if available) and send them to SIM800
  if(Serial.available())
  {    
    serialSIM800.write(Serial.read());
  }
```

### }

Non Working Output        -->

```
Setup Complete!
ATATAT
```

---

Working Output                -->

```
Setup Complete!
AT
OK
AT+CENG?
+CENG: 0,0

OK
AT+CNETSCAN
Operator:"405803",MCC:405,MNC:803,Rxlev:62,Cellid:51A5,Arfcn:702
Operator:"405803",MCC:405,MNC:803,Rxlev:51,Cellid:51A7,Arfcn:709
Operator:"405803",MCC:405,MNC:803,Rxlev:45,Cellid:35D6,Arfcn:703
Operator:"405803",MCC:405,MNC:803,Rxlev:37,Cellid:51A6,Arfcn:707
Operator:"Airtel",MCC:404,MNC:45,Rxlev:30,Cellid:08EC,Arfcn:53
Operator:"Airtel",MCC:404,MNC:45,Rxlev:28,Cellid:08E9,Arfcn:55
Operator:"Airtel",MCC:404,MNC:45,Rxlev:25,Cellid:08EA,Arfcn:103
Operator:"Airtel",MCC:404,MNC:45,Rxlev:18,Cellid:AF79,Arfcn:59
Operator:"Airtel",MCC:404,MNC:45,Rxlev:22,Cellid:186B,Arfcn:60
Operator:"Airtel",MCC:404,MNC:45,Rxlev:30,Cellid:08EB,Arfcn:61
Operator:"Hutch-Kamataka",MCC:404,MNC:86,Rxlev:51,Cellid:11B5,Arfcn:725
Operator:"Hutch-Kamataka",MCC:404,MNC:86,Rxlev:51,Cellid:11B4,Arfcn:666
Operator:"Spice Telecom",MCC:404,MNC:44,Rxlev:37,Cellid:0A5D,Arfcn:22
Operator:"Spice Telecom",MCC:404,MNC:44,Rxlev:34,Cellid:0A5B,Arfcn:25
Operator:"Spice Telecom",MCC:404,MNC:44,Rxlev:33,Cellid:0A5C,Arfcn:17
Operator:"Bharat Karnataka",MCC:404,MNC:71,Rxlev:21,Cellid:DB93,Arfcn:76
```

---

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are not sending NL and CR.
Make sure that Both NL & CR are selected for line ending.